# HTTP Content Negotiation/Compression: Use Base64 with Accept-Encoding/Content-Encoding?

Tags: http, base64, content-negotiation

I'm wondering if the following idea is working against the spirit and/or letter of [HTTP Content Negotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation) and [HTTP Compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression).

**The Situation**

The HTTP Client requests a resource:

```
HTTP GET /image.jpeg HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/jpeg
```

The HTTP Server returns this resource:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

**The Idea**

The Client thinks it's a good idea to request the resource *encoded*:

```
HTTP GET /image.jpeg HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/jpeg
Accept-Encoding: base64
```

The Server honors this request and returns the resource encoded:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Encoding: base64
```

**The Question**

I'm not quite happy with this idea. HTTP Compression, for which the `Accept-Encoding` and `Content-Encoding` headers are used, is about *compressing* data, not about *increasing* its size as Base64 does.

Is the use of `base64` as a value for these headers a violation of the spirit and/or letter of HTTP Content Negotiation and HTTP Content Compression?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[RFC 2616 section 3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.5) (emphasis mine):

> Content codings are primarily
> used to allow a document to be compressed **or otherwise usefully
> transformed** without losing the identity of its underlying media type
> and without loss of information.

Your idea is perfectly in line with the “spirit and letter” of HTTP.